# Dynamically changing key value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am checking the key in dictionary, if it contains `space` remove it.

```
def query_combination(sentence,mydict):
    for key in mydict.keys():
        if key == 'key':
            pass
        else:
            print 'key is : ',key
            if " " in key:                
                temp = key
                key = key.replace(' ',"")
                print 'new key : ',key                    
                sentence = sentence.replace(temp ,key)
                print 'new sentence : ',sentence
    print mydict
mydict = {'films': {'match': ['Space', 'Movie', 'six', 'two', 'one']}, u'Popeye Doyle': {'score': 100, 'match': [u'People', 'heaven', 'released']}}
sentence ='What films featured the character Popeye Doyle'
combination = query_combination(sentence,mydict)
```

I could not dynamically change the new key value to `mydict`. Any suggestion much appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a string out of the dictionary, and then change it and make a new string, the dictionary won't know about it; you can add a new entry to the dictionary and remove the old one:

```
        if " " in key:                
            newkey = key.replace(' ',"")
            mydict[newkey] = mydict[key]
            del mydict[key]

            print 'new key : ', newkey
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
def query_combination(sentence,mydict):
    for key in mydict.iterkeys():
        if " " in key:                
            temp = key
            mydict[key.replace(" ","")] = mydict[key] # create new key
            del mydict[key] # delete old key
            sentence = sentence.replace(temp ,key)
```

Another solution in one line would be

```
mydict[key.replace(" ","")] = mydict.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

`key = key.replace(' ',"")` does not affect the actual key in the dictionary, it is changing a copy of that key. You need to add the value to the dictionary with the new key and remove the old key. Here's one way to do it:

```
def query_combination(sentence, mydict):
    for old_key, new_key in [(key, key.replace(' ', '')) for key in mydict if ' ' in key]:
        mydict[new_key] = mydict.pop(old_key)
        sentence = sentence.replace(old_key, new_key)
```

Note, however, that you are replacing the key in the string `sentence`, but `sentence` is local to function `query_combination()`, so the outer scope `sentence` is unaffected by the replacement. I am not sure if that was what you hoped your code would do, but if it was you could simply return the revised `sentence` from the function, or include it as an item in the dictionary.

Given that `sentence` is not actually updated by your function, you can simplify the whole function to a mere dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> mydict = {'films': {'match': ['Space', 'Movie', 'six', 'two', 'one']}, u'Popeye Doyle': {'score': 100, 'match': [u'People', 'heaven', 'released']}}
>>> mydict = {key.replace(' ', '') : value for key, value in mydict.items()}
>>> mydict
{'films': {'match': ['Space', 'Movie', 'six', 'two', 'one']}, u'PopeyeDoyle': {'score': 100, 'match': [u'People', 'heaven', 'released']}}
```